# USB audio input has unusable amount of static

Tags: usb, audio

I'm using a raspberry pi zero to record audio. I have a usb audio dongle plugged in to it for the microphone. However, when I record with it, the input is EXTREMELY staticy. It's pretty much unusable. I tried plugging in the microphone into my computer and it works fine. I also tried a different microphone with a different USB input device and that was still unusable. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please explain the noise "staticy" ? Do you mean low frequency hum or literally wideband noisy static ?

Answer (score 2):

first try this:
arecord -f s16_LE -r 8000 -d 10 test8k.wav

and record "This is 10 seconds of 8 kilo-hertz 16 bit mono"

then play it back:

aplay test8k.wav

Much better?

```
========== If audio output is too soft - in command prompt can do: 
> alsamixer 
          s (select card)
          downarrow to “0 bcm2835 ALSA” 
          8      (4=default loudness, 8=100%, 9=125%)
          Escape (press Esc) then make setting default:    sudo alsactl store 0
```